# McNemar test or similar with multiple pairings?

Tags: classification, paired-data, agreement-statistics, mcnemar-test

Let's say I have test condition A and B, and a binary classification model. I have paired samples in conditions A and B, and I want to test if these conditions are different in classifier performance. My understanding is that McNemar's test is most appropriate here. However, what if I have multiple replicates, creating multiple possible pairings between conditions A and B?

For instance:

| Donor | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Donor 1 | + - + | - + + |

possible pairings:

| pairing 1 | pairing 2 |
| --- | --- |
| ++ | +- |
| -- | ++ |
| ++ | ++ |

The pairing on the left is 100% agreement, the pairing on the right is only 66% agreement. With multiple donors, you could optimistically pair every sample, pessimistically pair every sample, or agnostically pair every sample (always pair rep1, rep2, rep3, etc.)

This will effect the contingency table and thereby the McNemar test result. What is the best way to adjust for this? Or in this instance should I just use a Chi-squared or exact test? I have an idea, but I can't seem to find any literature on this topic.